# Is it possible to make a bukkit plugin that can take screenshots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

Well, I searched a lot, and couldn't find a single plugin that could, in a fixed time interval (of 15 minutes or so), take screenshots of an area ( For Example : spawn )

Still, I could have missed out on one, so if anyone knows of one, please do post.

Also, If it is not possible, is there an alternate way of doing it?

It is needed, as I want to spy on a 'griefer' who has a nasty habit of messing up the spawn.

I also happen to have a tiny bit knowledge of making a plugin, so even a push/help towards making one would also help. :)

Comment: If you're willing to write a bit of code, it *may* be possible to write a utility that takes a selected region and passes it to an external (?) program to save a screenshot. I don't know where you would start, though. It seems like that will be pretty complicated. Also, if you're worried about griefers in spawn, try using stuff like WorldGuard and CoreProtect.

Comment: I don't think bukkit plugin can do that but here are some mods/programs that might help you achieve this; http://sushenlab.com/ http://minecraft.curseforge.com/mc-mods/226312 http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/2327429 http://minecraft.curseforge.com/mc-mods/225875 https://miners-movies.com/desktop-recorder

Comment: @Whaaaaaat Well it is Agrarian Skies, and unfortunately the skyblock plugin has some loopholes maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking into making a screenshot of what a player actually sees, or to get an image file of how it looks like from within minecraft: No, that is not possible, since bukkit only works on the server-side.

If you're looking to get a snapshot of the current state of the world, any tool that can make a backup of your world should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still can u suggest some alternative way of tracking that down?
(choosing your answer as best atm :))

Answer (score 0):

If you willing to have a minecraft client always connected to the server...
you may use him tp where you want the screenshot and maybe that client can be 
setup to auto screenshot every 30 seconds lol...
or you may install a mod on that client that can be used as remote access by a plugin on the server so it takes a screenshot like when press F2...

Answer (score -1):

It is possible. But, it would be difficult since it cannot be done with just plain bukkit, you would need to have a program setup so it automatically renders/takes a screenshot.